# Просроченная электронная подпись на документах действует?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, цифровая-подпись

Если какой либо организацией был подписан pdf документ и выслана подпись, которую я проверил на сайте и мне выдало что все корректно, подпись действует и это действительно этот документ ей подписан.
Допустим на следующий день они потеряли эту подпись и отозвали, соответственно подпись уже не действительна, и при проверке документа скажет что подпись отозвана.
Но документ то уже подписан, и он у меня на руках, я могу доказать как то что он был корректно подписан до того как отозвали? Там же нигде не фигурирует дата фактического подписания? или фигурирует?
Получается что тот кто найдет эту подпись может так же ей подписать такой же документ и получить такую же подпись как у меня, которая будет так же просрочена?

Comment: Дата отзыва - вполне себе атрибут. Как и дата подписания. Не спрыгнуть.

Comment: А дата подписания где фигурирует?

Comment: Если она фигурирует в подписке, то что мешает человеку нашедшему флешку подписать с датой задним числом?

Comment: При отзыве сертификата фиксируется время отзыва. Если ты при проверке подписи документа зафиксируешь время проверки (или сайт, где выполнена проверка, фиксирует факт и время проверки) - то что тебя беспокоит? Подтверждённый факт проверки подписи документа в период действительности подписи, причём факт подтверждён третьей, незаинтересованной и сертифицированной, стороной (надеюсь, ты подпись проверяешь не в соседней подворотне?) - что ещё нужно?

Comment: Лучше бы им переподписать. Время в цифровой подписи ничего не доказывает, так как метка времени не из доверенного источника.